# Mongoose set default object id in schema

Tags: mongoose

I want to do this in my schema declaration:

```
Member : { 
           type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
           ref: 'otherMember', 
           default: ObjectId("123") 
         }
```

Where `otherMember` is the other instantiated Schema with a document inside it of ObjectId `123`.

Node shows me error messages. How to achieve?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

As you set the *type* to **Schema.Types.ObjectId** you have to set the default as a **string** and it's given as the argument of ObjectId so your example should be:

```
Member : { 
           type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
           ref: 'otherMember', 
           default: '123' 
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [pre hook](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) mongoose. Like this

```
/* ECMASCript6 */

import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const SchemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;

const YourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
         roles: [{ //put your model field
            type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Role'
           }]
  });
```

> and then in pre hook:

```
  YourSchema.pre('save', (next) => {
  if(this.roles.length === 0){
    this.roles.push(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5962a5f37bde228394da6f72"))//this _id ref your model
  }
  next();//important!
});
```